# numpy.loadtxt and tab separated values: data type not understood

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having problems importing tab separated values using `numpy.loadtxt`.

The rows I need to import have the following form:

```
01-Aug-2013 1143_051-100    r   702 135 32  7
```

I only want to read columns 0,2,3,4,5,6. This is what I have so far:

```
numpy.loadtxt(test,dtype= (str,str,int,int,int,int), delimiter= "\t", usecols = (0,2,3,4,5,6))
```

This returns `data type not understood`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve fast indexing, NumPy relies on each dtype having a fixed width. So if you specify a string dtype, you also have to specify the number of bytes in the string. So

```
dtype = '|S11,|S1,<i4,<i4,<i4,<i4'
```

would work for the data you posted.

However, it is easier to use `np.genfromtxt` instead of `np.loadtxt` when the strings have variable width, since you can specify `dtype=None` and let `np.genfromtxt` make an educated guess about the dtype of each column.

---

```
In [15]: np.genfromtxt('data', delimiter='\t', dtype=None, usecols=(0,2,3,4,5,6))
Out[15]: 
array(('01-Aug-2013', 'r', 702, 135, 32, 7), 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S11'), ('f1', 'S1'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<i4'), ('f5', '<i4')])
```

or

```
In [16]: np.loadtxt('data', delimiter='\t', dtype='|S11,|S1,<i4,<i4,<i4,<i4', usecols=(0,2,3,4,5,6))
Out[16]: 
array(('01-Aug-2013', 'r', 702, 135, 32, 7), 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S11'), ('f1', 'S1'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<i4'), ('f5', '<i4')])
```