# ValueError in Python 3; specifically jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to read in a file

the text file itself is laid out in 9 columns with tons of data (454 lines total)

I'm trying to read in and retrieve certain columns of data so I can plot a diagram of the mass related to temperature (an HR diagram)

however when I try to load the text using:

```
file = 'nameoftext.txt' #the file itself is saved as a txt from notepad++
track1 = np.loadtext(file, skiprows=70) #im skipping 70 rows of headers to the data (and np is numpy)
```

I get an error saying:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'iso'
```

I have no idea what this means or what I'm doing.

I'm also using `np.loadtext` because that's the only way my professor showed us how to load files and I have no idea how else to do it.

Comment: Numpy only accepts numbers. There must've been strings mixed in the CSV.

Comment: @riddler that is not exactly true you can put a string with correct encoding in numpy arrays

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load text file as strings using numpy.loadtxt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985233/load-text-file-as-strings-using-numpy-loadtxt)

Comment: If you know the data type of your 9 columns (which you should), you can specify them manually like `dtype='str,int, int, str, int, int, str, float, int',`. Otherise you can use `np.genfromtxt` and specify `dtype=None`. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839654/numpy-loadtxt-and-tab-separated-values-data-type-not-understood)

Comment: No need to blame Jupyter for this. Just saying

Answer (score 0):

another option for loading .txt files in the python is the genfromtxt() function also in numpy. In this function the object type of values in each column can be specified or you can allow the function to guess the type on its own.

Check out the link below for a similar question.
[Loading text file containing both float and string using numpy.loadtxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546349/loading-text-file-containing-both-float-and-string-using-numpy-loadtxt)